# A conjecture on consecutive odd composite numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, prime-factorization

Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the claim given below?

Inspired by [Grimm's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grimm%27s_conjecture) I have formulated the following claim:

> Let $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$ be a sequence of $k$ consecutive odd numbers which are all composite. Let $\operatorname{gpf}(n_i)$ be the greatest prime factor of $n_i$. Then, all $\operatorname{gpf}(n_i)$, $1 \le i \le k$ are mutually different.

[Try it yourself.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwtyrsOwiAUBuCdp0AmLk0ajE4njH0K0wEr1ROEEqDWx7emTP8lXy_pEKvL1NK4hvtePJU98eZyBYJGA9le-Hb8hCUVtz6WlDE4fpZeadHtI1bOIkNm2PHBbKe65GKObBKafKaZ_7Uw7OOmYL-88VtH9SgEoFLglRLwAwmnLoA=&lang=gp)

Comment: "be a greatest" --> "be the greatest". also, what's $k$?

Comment: $3,5,7,9$. $3$ is the greatest prime factor of $3$ and $9$

Comment: @mathworker21 $3,5,7$ are not composite numbers...

Comment: ah, my apologies. what is $k$ though?

Comment: @mathworker21 $k$ is arbitrary number .

Comment: ok, well, if your claim were true, then Grimm's conjecture is true. so probably the best someone on MSE can do is prove it false, which most likely means finding an explicit counterexample..

Comment: A simpler version of your conjecture is that if $n$ and $m$ are odd, $n< m$, and $\text{gpf}(n)=\text{gpf}(m)$ then there is a prime in the interval $[n,m]$

Comment: If your conjecture is true, then for any prime $p$, there exists a prime between $p(p-2)$ and $p^2$. (There gpfs are $p$) Showing it is likely to be as hard as proving that there exists a prime between $n$ and $n+k\sqrt{n}$ for some constant $k$, which is open problem as of now. (Currently it's proven only for $n+n^{0.525}$)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A conterexample: gpf(20449) = gpf(20475) = 13, and there are no prime numbers between them. According to my program's results, it is the only counterexample up to 1000000.